# Lapack64 cannot find

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am new to Linux and trying to run a program that requires lapack, however when I type `-L /usr/lib64 -llapack64`, this error appears `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack64`.

I've installed it again, and changed the directory to just `lib`, but even if I write `locate lapack64` nothing appears. If any of you guys know how to resolve this please let me now.

Answer (score 0):

I did not need to call Lapack64, because it was already in Pardiso. The real problem was how I was calling Pardiso.

My pardiso licence was in a different place then the one were I thought it was. I had to change the directory in `pardiso.conf`.

Then I had to do `ldconfig` and it worked.

So basically if you write `-llapack -L/usr/lib -L<the directory the license is>` this problem is solved.

Comment: can you make your answer clearer for other users?

Comment: So I did not needed to call lapack64, lapack64 is already in pardiso, but the pardiso licence was in a different place then the one were I thought it was. I had to change the directory in pardiso.conf after that do ldconfig (something I forgot) and it worked. So basically I needed to write -llapack -L/usr/lib -L/the directory the license is. 
Sorry I'm new in this foruns is this helpful?

Comment: Please edit your answer, not explain it more in comments.

Comment: right....sorry about that

Comment: No problem. You're quite new to the site so that's understandable. I've edited your answer for formatting. If you approve that, I'll upvote you right away.